# Which word can indicate all the meanings included in a certain belief or notion?

Tags: word-choice

I'm having trouble with the word-choice in my thesis. For example, I'm talking about Romanticism as a literary style, including its characteristics, principles, etc. But before my discussion I want to make a general statement: Next we are going to discuss the "which word" of Romanticism, and this word should indicate the core content of a notion, belief, or trend. I am not sure if the word "connotation(s)" is correct.

Comment: I have no idea what is meant by "which word* in your query. Regardless, why wouldn't *genre* work as a preferred choice?

Comment: Check out synonyms of ***fundamentals***

Comment: 'Ramifications' has the intended sense (a **related** or derived subject, problem, etc ... [Dictionary.com; see Google listing], but the default sense is '[especially unexpected and often multiple] consequence/s', so suboptimal. Perhaps just 'and all that that term implies' is best.

Answer (score 1):

> Next we are going to discuss the **concepts** of Romanticism.

**Strength Of Materials: A Practical Approach** - 2017 -

> Discuss the concepts of the method of tension coefficients , and explain why it is preferred to analyse space trusses . --

**The Emerald Handbook of Entrepreneurship in Tourism,**  2018...

> Discuss the concepts of creative industry and business creation. --

**“We” and “the Others”. Islam in Europe** Andreas Schulz · 2016...

> discuss the concepts of Islam in the western world

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear: you first talk about "meaning included" (not very idiomatic, by the way), and the sense of "meaning" has to be taken as "that which a word, phrase or sentence is to convey or that which is the interpretation of a dream or action" (paraphrase of the SOED). This sense allows you to say  "the meaning of the *word* 'Romanticism'". If you want to preserve idiomaticity, you have to consider another sense of "meaning", that is, its secondary sense, as  "importance, significance" ("the meaning of Romanticism"). However, you finally mention the term "core content", and again it is not possible to speak of the "content of Romanticism" because this is not an idiomatic term. You may however consider the  "content"  of a *word* where content stands for "meaning" (recently introduced in the language, 21rst century));  it seems likely then that the question has to do with the main meaning of "meaning". A word that identifies the idea contained in "core content", as pertains to words, is "gist".

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/gist?q=gist)) **gist** noun /dʒɪst/
> ​gist (of something) the main or general meaning of a piece of writing, a speech or a conversation

[image]

[image: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gist+of+the+word%2Ccrux+of+the+word%2Cgist+of+Romanticism%2Ccrux+of+Romanticism&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3]

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the word you are looking for is *characteristics*:

> *Next we will discuss the characteristics of Romanticism.*

> **characteristic** *noun* & *adjective*
>  NOUN
> **1.a.** A distinctive mark, trait, or feature that may serve for identification; a distinguishing or essential peculiarity or quality.
> With *of*.
>  <sub>Source: [*Oxford English
> Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login required)</sub>

Here is an [example from Study.com](https://study.com/academy/lesson/romanticism-in-literature-definition-characteristics.html):

> **What are the characteristics of Romanticism in literature?**
>  The main characteristics of Romanticism include the celebration of the
> sublime or awe-inspiring powers of nature, the glorification of
> individuality and emotion, the rebellion against tradition and
> rationality, and the infusion of spiritual and supernatural elements.